# How to achieve single sign-on before and after separation?

Tags: javascript, php, python, node.js, single-sign-on

Assuming the api interface is `api.a.com`, the login operation is done at
`login.a.com`, and the login state is realized when `b.com` and `c.com` are accessed. After login, End will return a token user ID, either `cookie` or `localStorage` are not cross-domain access, cross-site can get the user ID, save the user state?
I do not know much about SSO, I hope we can provide a solution.
If you can provide a demo of `Node.js`, that's a big thank you.
The above is the result of Google translation, if there are errors, please forgive me, thank you

Comment: Um, you need to clarify which languages you're using. This is REST stuff, so it should not need any specific language. First you need to know the REST api's of the sites you need to contact, then test them in Postman. When you can obtain the tokens correctly, implement cURL or similar in whichever language you are actually going to use to make the calls to the api.

Comment: REST api's do not require you to use any specific language. You just need anything that can make an outbound HTTP call and retain the response.

Comment: But definitely get the request right in Postman first.